# SQL Server 2014 - parallel processes Insert same value in table with unique index

Tags: sql-server, parallel-processing, insert, unique-index

I have a table called dbo.mtestUnique with two column id and desc, I have a unique index on "desc" , two process inserting data to this table at a same time, how can I avoid inserting duplicate value and violating the unique index?

not exists and left join doesn't work.

to replicate this you can create a table on a test database:

```
CREATE TABLE mtestUnique
(
    id INT ,
    [DESC] varchar(50),
    UNIQUE([DESC])
)
```

and then run the following script on two different queries on SSMS.

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
DECLARE @time VARCHAR(50)

WHILE (1=1)
BEGIN 
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t') IS NOT NULL 
        DROP TABLE #t

    SELECT @time = CAST(DATEPART(HOUR , GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(10)) + ':' + RIGHT('00' +CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE , GETDATE())+1 AS VARCHAR(2)),2)

    SELECT MAX(id) + 1 id , 'test' + @time [DESC] 
        INTO #t
    FROM dbo.mtestUnique

    -- to insert as exact same time
    WAITFOR TIME @time

        INSERT INTO dbo.mtestUnique
                ( id, [DESC] )
        SELECT *
        FROM #t t
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                        SELECT 1
                        FROM dbo.mtestUnique u
                        WHERE u.[DESC] = t.[Desc]

                         )

END
```

I even put the insert in a TRAN but no luck.

thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Can you use [Identity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) on the ID column?

Comment: how it gonna help?

Comment: If you need a unique desc, then make it unique, not just time. Use, e.g. NEWID() or current session_ID + time.

Comment: Sorry. I misread the question! If you don't want the constraint violation you will need to set up some sort of reservation system where the first query to check for existence makes a reservation.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to prevent a unique constraint violation is to not insert duplicate values for the column.  If you have the unique constraint, it will throw an error when you try to insert a duplicate description, but it will not control what descriptions are attempted to be inserted.

With that said, if you only need a unique identifier I would highly recommend using the ID instead.  Set it to an auto incriminating integer and do not insert in manually.  Just provide the description and SQL Server will populate the ID for you avoiding duplicates.

Comment: This is just a sample, let say I have a table for Usernames and username is meant to be unique so I put a unique constraint on it and now different processes are trying to insert userName in that table. in this case I don't need an ID or identifier. <br/> "The only way to prevent a unique constraint violation is to not insert duplicate values for the column." <br/> that's why I put not exists.

Comment: Yes, if you only want a unique username then a unique constraint would be all you need, although I would highly recommend an auto incriminating integer, if not as the primary key then at least with an index against it, if the usernames will be joined against any other tables.

What issue are you seeing?  Are one of the queries failing with a constraint violation while attempting the insert?  Even if you wait till @time, one of the inserts should have a lock on the table so they will not actually insert in parallel.

Comment: Exactly, one process is supposed to have a lock and second process should wait until the first one is done, and then on insert it should evaluate the "not exists" and insert the rows without violation of unique constraint, BUT looks like sql server does it differently. I think sql server asks for IU lock on table and evaluates the "not exist" statement on both processes, and on insert step one process escalates the lock to U and  the second process wait for lock on this step.

Comment: That is strange, although the details of what locks are used when is beyond my.  While you could research it to determine how to avoid the constraints by timing the queries, I would just use a try catch statement for each record being inserted.  This way, a unique constraint violation does not kill the query unless you include that in your catch statement.